# Query using geom_bar() of ggplot2 - R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a similar data frame as follows:

```
mapDF <- structure(list(var = c(11L, 3L, 4L, 15L, 19L, 17L, 1L), approvals = c(10.5233545765422, 
67.9809421770218, 9.66394835013545, 2.93736399165075, 3.36787205222721, 
4.0168261757783, 1.50969267664431)), .Names = c("var", "approvals"
), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

When I try creating a bar graph using the data frame above using:

```
gplot <- ggplot(mapDF, aes(x= mapDF[1], y= mapDF[2])) + geom_bar()
```

.. I get the following messages with **nothing** showing up in the 'Plots' section of RStudio:

```
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type data.frame. Defaulting to continuous
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type data.frame. Defaulting to continuous
Error: stat_bin requires the following missing aesthetics: x
```

Can anyone please point out my error?

Comment: Ever notice how in all the ggplot code you've ever seen people map aesthetics inside `aes` using the _name_ of the column...? :)

Comment: (And you will want `stat = "identity"` inside `geom_bar`.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rolling @joran's comments into an answer:

```
ggplot(mapDF, aes(x=var, y=approvals)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```